# Incorporate echo result in an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my second visit here needing a helping hand. My first visit was a massive success so thought i'd come back! :)

I have an array as follows...

```
<?php
$args = array (
    "type" => "post",
    "author" => $stalybridge,
    "posts_per_page" => 10,
"meta_key" => "event_date_time",
    "order" => "ASC",
    "orderby" => "meta_value",
);
?>
```

I would like to replace the $stalybridge with the result from the following...

```
<?php
$stalybridge = mysql_query("SELECT author FROM directory WHERE area='Stalybridge'");
$output = '';
echo"'";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stalybridge))
{ 
$output .= $row['author'] . ",";
}
echo rtrim( $output, "," );
echo"'";
?>
```

Ive managed to get the echo result to look exactly as it needs to be and if I paste the result '7,17,25,28,32,35,45,48,111,125,131' straight into the array it works fine but I cant seem to combine the two!

Dont know if I'm barking up the wrong tree trying to do it this way but I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks,

Comment: are you meaning `$args["author"] = rtrim( $output, "," );`?

Comment: I need to replace the $stalybridge from the "author" => $stalybridge, part with '7,17,25,28,32,35,45,48,111,125,131' which is the result from the echo code...

Comment: well if you do `$args["author"] = rtrim( $output, "," );` in place of `echo rtrim( $output, "," );` it will replace the `$stalybridge` in `"author" => $stalybridge` with the value in `$output`.

Answer (score 0):

Hacking the Wordpress core usually results in these types of confusing elements. You should have used the `wp_posts` table to store this and then used the `wp_usermeta` table to make references.

Anyway, you can do a simple array replacement on the key.

```
$array['author'] = $row['author'];
$output .= $row['author'] . ",";
```

Each iteration of your while loop will make change that value, so it's likely you'll want to query those posts within your iteration loop (This is bad practice and I don't recommend it, but is the result of circumventing the core of WP).

```
$result = new WP_Query($array);
if($result->have_posts()):
    while($result->have_posts()): $result->the_post();
        //standard wordpress post functions, the_title();, the_author(); etc..
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I started building my site without any knowledge of SQL / PHP at all so have learnt what I know as I've gone along. I just use WP as a backend, kind of a CMS, so have had to hack it to make it do what I needed. Looking back, probably not the best move and some of the code in there, knowing what I know now, is appalling! It needs re building from the ground up but years of work have gone into it so wont be a 5 minute job!
Thanks for the reply though, not sure I quite understand it yet but I'll have a go, see if I can figure it out.
Thanks again! :)